# 500 error from Facebook when attempting to create group

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to code a Facebook app that can create groups, but it's not working. My minimal complete example, which you can poke at [here](https://ab2c9e8ec58ef7281026b094d12677ce003e1ddf.googledrive.com/host/0B26WWPDYpNnYLUdXVzJaSnNMdzA/) (I couldn't get the Facebook API to work on jsFiddle), is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Group</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '784633881599418',
          xfbml: true,
          version: 'v2.2'
        });
        document.getElementById('create').addEventListener('click',
          function() {
            FB.login(function() {
              FB.ui({
                method: 'game_group_create',
                name: 'Test Group',
                description: 'This is a test. Only a test.',
                privacy: 'CLOSED'
              }, function(response) {
                if (response && response.id) {
                  alert('Success: ' + response.id);
                } else {
                  alert('Error.');
                }
              });
            });
          }, false);
      };
      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
          return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/debug.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <button id="create">Create Group</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks the button, they're prompted to log in (if they haven't already) and authorize the app (if they haven't already), exactly as you'd expect. But after that, a Facebook box appears in the middle of the window with a perpetual loading indicator. Meanwhile, the following errors are logged to the console:

- `GET https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=784633881599418…4d12677ce003e1ddf.googledrive.com%252Ff13eb6ab9%26relation%3Dparent.parent 500 (Internal Server Error)`
- `Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=784633881599418…4d12677ce003e1ddf.googledrive.com%252Ff13eb6ab9%26relation%3Dparent.parent' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.`

What's going on, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

So I commented out `FB.login(function() {` and the corresponding `});` and that fixed it.